# Splitting Data Frames Dynamically in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to split a data frame dynamically but it's not working (here's a simple example):

```
e = {'cat' : pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])}
cat = pd.DataFrame(e)
cat.head(5)

def splitter(val, outval):
    outval = pd.DataFrame(cat['cat'] == "val")
```

What i'm hoping to do is create a dataset for each value in the variables: i'm hoping the function would create a data frame called 'A' which would contain the value 'A'..

```
splitter('A', 'myset')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with what you have.  Mainly, you aren't doing your function properly, and you're trying to call the string "val", not the variable `val` in your equality.  Try this:

```
data = {'cat' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 'dog' : ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

def splitter(df, val):
    return df[df['cat'] == val]

val = 'A'    
df_subset = splitter(df, val)
```

This leaves you with two dataframes:

```
>df
   cat dog
0   A   e
1   B   f
2   C   g
3   D   h

>df_subset
   cat dog
0   A   e
```

There's actually no need for a function to do that, but I left it in there so you can see how the function works.  In particular note that you don't pass `outval` into it, when that's what you want it to return.

A few other side notes:

Dataframes can be created from a dictionary with the values as lists, so there's no need to call `Series`.

Don't name your dataframe object the same thing as the dataframe columns you'll be referring to (in this case "cat") because it's just confusing.  If you're only dealing with one dataframe, convention is to use `df`.

Instead of making a splitter function, for something this simple you can just do: `df_subset = df[df['cat'] == val]`, unless this was just a toy example and more needs to happen inside the function, of course.

Comment: thanks, almost there: do you know how i could dynamically pass the name of 'A' in the final data frame name? so that df_subset is called df_subset_a instead? that way different subsets would be created for each value of 'cat'

Comment: It could be done inside of a loop.  For example: `for name in ['A', 'B', 'C]: df[df['cat'] == name]` would do it three times, once for each item in the list. The specifics would depend on what you want to iterate over and what you want to do with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can access dataframes in an easier way:

```
cata = cat[cat['cat'] == 'A']
catb = cat[cat['cat'] == 'B']
```

Note that pandas gives you a view or a copy, which depends on context. This is explained in: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

What this means is that when you return views, they are backed up by the underlying dataset. When you get a copy, then modifications to that copy are not reflected in the original dataset.

What this means is that you need to take care when you manipulate the result afterwards. If it's a copy, you'll get many warnings if write actions occur.

You seem to create dataframes for everything, so probably are only interested in the copies. In that case your concern is mostly whether it all fits into memory or not.

Comment: thanks but i want to dynamically create the data frame so that i dont have to type 'cata' or 'catb' but the values 'A' and 'B' are fed through automatically to CAT'A' or CAT'B'..